# Javascript weird behavior with new String() object reference

Tags: javascript

I am learning Js Oops then i came across this weird thing, i tried following code in chrome console.

http://puu.sh/6AT5H.png

or here is the code

```
 >> var name = new String(undefined);
 >> undefined
 >> name
 >> "undefined"
 >> var nString = new String(undefined);
 >> undefined
 >> nString
 >> String {0: "u", 1: "n", 2: "d", 3: "e", 4: "f", 5: "i", 6: "n", 7: "e", 8: "d", length: 9}
```

one variable (name) returns a string , while the other variable(nString) returns object, how is it possible.