# JavaScript: var name is not undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, var

```
var name;
console.log(name === undefined); // returns false
```

Why is this? Isn't name supposed to be undefined since no value has been assigned to it?

If I try the same for, let's say, `var asd;` it will assign it to be undefined. Is `name` a special keyword or something?

Thank you.

Comment: You defined the variable, so it's defined....

Comment: `window.name`. Make it a local variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in

Comment: This is a duplicate (although I cannot find the specific question for this specific issue) - it's an odd "edge case" of `var name` in *global scope*, as `var` does not declare a new variable in that context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029234/why-global-variable-name-changes-to-string

Comment: @user2864740: Any of the ones mentioned here?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link. I did looked up my question on stackoverflow but did not find that thread.

Comment: @Arthlete: Well I knew that I had to search for "window.name" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the global scope of the browser `name` is a property of `Window` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name